# How to format XML data that is requested from a JSP into a table

Tags: java, xml, jsp

I have a .jsp which determines what specific things a user has access to. It creates an XML file which is read into a stream by the previous jsp. How would I populate a table with the XML data which is read into a char array stream?

Comment: Yes, an html table. However, right now the XML is in a character array stream so the XML is in plaintext...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to get a HTML table out of the XML file. One of the most clean ways is to parse that XML into a collection of reuseable [javabeans](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javabeans/info) which you pass to the JSP, so that you can use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:forEach>` to iterate over it while rendering a HTML table. This way every layer keeps its own clear responsibility. The Java SE provided [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/) is very helpful in this.

Imagine that your XML look like this:

```
<data>
    <entry>
        <key>foo1</key>
        <value>bar1</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>foo2</key>
        <value>bar2</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>foo3</key>
        <value>bar3</value>
    </entry>
</data>
```

Then you can create a JAXB javabean as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Data {

    @XmlElement(name="entry")
    private List<Entry> entries;

    public List<Entry> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }

    public static class Entry {

        @XmlElement
        private String key;

        @XmlElement
        private String value;

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

    }

}
```

Then you can transform it into a `List<Entry>` as follows:

```
List<Entry> entries = JAXBContext.newInstance(Data.class).createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(inputStream).getEntries();
```

Then you can let your [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) (or JSP? :/ ) store it in the request scope before forwarding the request to the JSP:

```
request.setAttribute("entries", entries);
```

Finally you can in JSP iterate over it and present it as a HTML table:

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${entries}" var="entry">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${entry.key}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${entry.value}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Using your method to create the stream of the XML file, the data shows up as plaintext rather than XML. Does that matter at all?

Comment: Yes, something's wrong in your code (or your question was actually incomplete, all I understood is that you want to present a XML structure as a HTML table).

Comment: I got the XML data from the function using your method in my other question. I printed that data using a BufferedReader. I'm guessing the XML in the inputStream is still untouched...? So, will this method still apply?

Comment: I don't understand why you are printing it using `BufferedReader` instead of feeding it to JAXB. Please keep in mind that an `InputStream` can be read only once. If you want to debug its contents, just do `System.out.println(entries);` after getting the collection of useable Java objects out of it.

Comment: I just printed it to see if your method worked. I wasn't sure if the XML was actually there because I guess it got process by the .jsp. How would I see the actual XML that is created so I can get an idea of how to format the bean?

Comment: Just open the desired URL in the browser address bar?

Comment: Or, do you mean that you're seeing the JSTL tags unparsed in generated HTML result? (this is a somewhat different from seeing "plain text"...) If so, did you declare the JSTL taglib in top of JSP? Click the "JSTL" link in my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use XSLT to style the XML as it is or use XPath to navigate over the XML and build an table that fits your needs.

But not sure if embedding that logic is clean, I would rather that was processed in a bean and you could get the final list from a bean that the jsp can use to produce the table.

http://oreilly.com/catalog/javaxslt/chapter/ch05.html

Answer (score 0):

So in your JSP you've got nothing other than the InputStream that is the raw XML document?  It seems to me that you have little choice but to learn the Java libraries for processing XML.

Google search "XML Processing in Java" and you'll see the myriad of options available to you.  Even the "XSLT to transform your XML to something you can deal with in the HTML of the page" recommendation above is going to require you to parse this stream.  The JAXB API (http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_1_2-Overview.html#Overview) makes this a little less painful, allowing you to map the XML document into POJOs.

Anyway you look at it, processing this at the JSP level is a bit of a code smell.  You should process the XML stream somewhere else and send your JSP the POJO results for presentation.

My 2 cents worth.