# parse a xml and pass the values in tr td of a html table

Tags: html, jsp

In JSP, I need to parse an XML to get values and store them in an HTML table with one field as `ROWS=tr` of a table and each `VALUE=td` of table

xml:

```
<Rows>
    <Row>
        <Value>abc</Value>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Value>CV-0000000063-Process</Value>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Value>F003</Value>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Value>HR</Value>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Value>2017-09-22 00:00:00.0</Value>
    </Row>
</Rows>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us some code. Ideally you do not run business code within your jsp, since this is the view layer.

Comment: you have to show us your code so that we can help! But first of all there is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841002/how-to-format-xml-data-that-is-requested-from-a-jsp-into-a-table) which shows you How to format XML data that is requested from a JSP into a table! try also this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_xml_data.htm) for JSP - XML Data!